# ruby how to split by(':') and return 2/3 split part

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
message_id = 'apple:grape:honey'
access_token = message_id.split(':')[1]
#=> "grape"
```

i want to return  `'grape:honey'`

how to do it? Help me please

Comment: Is your code valid, to begin with?

Comment: `message_id[/(?<=:).*/]` returns the part after the first `:`

Comment: you can also use partition `message_id.partition(':')[-1]`, more here https://apidock.com/ruby/String/partition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very easy

```
message = 'apple:grape:honey'
message.split(':',2)[1]
```

It will return

```
'grape:honey'
```

[image]

Comment: Now the answer is same as given by @Igor, except for the obvious `[1]`.

Comment: Where you are executing the  lines. There are no syntax error.

Answer (score 9):

Ruby's [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) accepts `limit` as the second argument:

```
'apple:grape:honey'.split(':', 2) # => ["apple", "grape:honey"]
```

If limit is a positive number, at most that number of fields will be returned (if limit is 1, the entire string is returned as the only entry in an array).